# Forward and merge input of Apache Beam Transform to its output

Tags: python, parallel-processing, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Let's say I have a data transformation (like map) that takes some dict input and outputs some other dict
I dont have control over what exactly is in the output dict of the transformation, and I want to merge the whole input dict with the output dict produced by the transformation.

```
import apache_beam as beam


with beam.Pipeline() as pipeline:
  (pipeline 
   | 'Create data' >> beam.Create([
          {'A': 2},
          {'A': 3},
      ])
   | 'Transform' >> beam.Map(lambda d: {'B': d['A']*2})
```

What can I do to merge the Map input data with the result in an efficient manner (lets assume I cannot change the function in the Map to return the original A).
So the expetected collection would be:
`[{'A': 2, 'B': 4}, {'A': 3, 'B': 6}]`

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that by this

> (lets assume I cannot change the function in the Map to return the original A)

You mean that for some reason you're unable to simply return the dict from your transform already merged.

I would recommend keying the data in a way that both the original dicts and the corresponding transformed dicts share the same key. Then use a [`Combine.PerKey`](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#combine) to merge dicts that share the same key.

So step by step, first you'll want to write a `beam.Map` to associate each input dict with a randomly generated key (or some other uniquely identifying property if one already exists). Then when you transform the dicts, make sure to preserve the key. Then feed both keyed PCollections (before and after transforming) to a `Flatten` to put them in the same PCollection, followed by a `GroupByKey` to group both the "before" and "after" dicts into one list under the key.

Finally, use a `Combine.PerKey` with a custom `CombineFn` using the Create Accumulator, Add Input, Merge Accumulators, and Extract Output methods. In this case, the accumulator type will also be a dict, and Merge Accumulators will merge dicts together. Since dicts will only be merged per-key, this should properly merge the corresponding dicts from before and after your transform. You can strip the keys from each element after this, if necessary.

Comment: but from my understanding, this would reduce the whole data pipeline. 
What is to basically zip the original inputs with the outputs of the Map, so that there's still a separate dict for every input dict

Comment: Oops, you're right. I misread the question. I updated my answer, hopefully this one actually answers the question.